# Can I change log file location in the script, using Groovy or Java, for example?

Tags: redirect, logging, jmeter

Now I run jmeter script this way:

```
"C:\Users\Anton Starodub\Desktop\Soft\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter" -n -t "path\test_script.jmx" -l "path\jmeter.jtl" -j "path\Results\jmeter.log"
```

Can I set jmeter.log and jmeter.jtl inside the script and do not include it in the command?

So the command I want is:

```
"C:\Users\Anton Starodub\Desktop\Soft\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter" -n -t "path\test_script.jmx" -J RESULT_DIR="path"
```

So I will process the RESULT_DIR inside the script, and store the jmeter.log and the jmeter.jtl there.

I tried `System.setProperty("jmeter.logfile", path);`, but does not seem to work in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible, at least not with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

If you don't want to set these 2 parameters each time you run your test:

1. For .jtl results file you can:

   - just don't provide the .jtl file name via `-l` argument
   - and if you need the results (hope you do) you can add a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) line [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and configure what and where to store.
2. For the log file you can set the desired location in the [log4j2.xml file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/log4j2.xml#L35)